# How to split multiple columns with comma separated values into different rows while maintaining value sequence in the different columns?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Using VBA, how to split an excel table containing few columns with common data and remaining columns containing comma separated values. The table format is something like

[image]

And the expected result is something like

[image]

Tried using Power Query but static data is repeated with actions done on each comma separated column data.

Comment: Using VBA, do you want to overwrite or a new table (in another worksheet)?

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your issue? You have not accepted any of them

Answer (score 2):

This is one way in powerquery

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table.FromColumns({Text.Split([Column3],","),Text.Split([Column4],","),Text.Split([Column5],",")})),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column3", "Column4", "Column5"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}, {"Column3", "Column4", "Column5"})
in #"Expanded Custom"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm takes as input 1) a ListObject object, 2) a cell where to place the new table 3) the separator string and 4) the index of the columns whose content we want to break into multiple lines. The table can have as many columns as need and one more thing: The cells we want to partition do not have to have the same number of elements, for example column2 a,b,c column3 a,b,c,d

Then follows another Function which does the exact opposite. It takes the new expanded table and converts it to the form of the original one, also having an option not to have (internal) duplicate values in the columns made by concatenation. Although it doesn't answer the question, I'm posting it here because it's interrelated with the answer, it's an "undo" of the result of the answer.

```
Option Explicit

'this EVENT in a sheet module, call the sub with the parameters
Private Sub BT_EXPAND_Click()
   Dim expTbl As ListObject
   Const separator = ","
   Set expTbl = expand_table(Me.ListObjects("TABLEA"), Me.Range("A8"), separator, 3, 4, 5)
   If Not expTbl Is Nothing Then
      Call shrink_table(expTbl, Me.Range("A" & (expTbl.ListRows.Count + 11)), False, separator, 3, 4, 5)
   End If
End Sub

'****************************************************************************
'* COPY THIS PUBLIC FUNCTION IN A MODULE
'* CAN USE IT FOR ANY TABLE WITH ANY ROWS/COLUMNS
'* ----------------PARAMETERS--------------------
'* ListObject> the table object to expand its data
'* topLeftOfNewTable> the cell to fit the top-left corner of the new table
'* separator> separator string of concatenated values at columns we tranform
'* colsWithComma> ParamArray with indexes of columns to transform eg 3,5,6,7
'****************************************************************************
Public Function expand_table(ByRef t As ListObject, topLeftOfNewTable As Range, separator As String, _
                             ParamArray colsWithComma() As Variant) As ListObject
   Dim rws As Long, clmns As Long, r As Long, c As Long, tex As ListObject, clarr() As Variant, strFlag As String
   Dim lbWc As Integer, ubWc As Integer, z As Integer, zidx As Integer, tmpUb As Integer, maxExp As Integer, lrw As ListRow
   Dim ccex As Integer
   
   lbWc = LBound(colsWithComma)
   ubWc = UBound(colsWithComma)
   If ubWc < 0 Then Exit Function 'nothing todo
   
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   
   rws = t.DataBodyRange.Rows.CountLarge
   clmns = t.DataBodyRange.Columns.CountLarge
   
   'CREATE A STRING WITH AS MANY SPACES AS THE COLUMNS OF TABLE
   'AT POSITIONS OF colsWithComma() SET "*" (FLAG THE POSITION COLUMNS TO EXPAND)
   strFlag = Space$(clmns)
   For z = lbWc To ubWc
      If colsWithComma(z) <= clmns Then
         Mid$(strFlag, colsWithComma(z), 1) = "*"
      Else
         MsgBox ("expand_table> Column " & colsWithComma(z) & " out of table bounds - max=" & clmns)
      End If
   Next
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'IF ALREADY EXISTS A TABLE IN THE POSTOTION OF THE NEW, DELETE IT
   If Not topLeftOfNewTable.ListObject Is Nothing Then
      topLeftOfNewTable.ListObject.Delete
   End If
   
   'CREATE NEW TABLE TO EXPORT THE ORIGINAL
   Set tex = topLeftOfNewTable.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, topLeftOfNewTable.Resize(1, t.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count), , xlYes)
   'COPY THE HEADER LINE
   t.HeaderRowRange.Copy topLeftOfNewTable
   
   'redim the array to hold the arrays of columns values, when split them
   ReDim clarr(lbWc To ubWc)
   
   For r = 1 To rws
      ' in every row find the column with the maximum elements after split
      maxExp = 0
      For z = lbWc To ubWc
         clarr(z) = Split(t.ListRows(r).Range.Cells(, colsWithComma(z)), separator)
         tmpUb = UBound(clarr(z))
         If tmpUb > maxExp Then maxExp = tmpUb
      Next
      
      'WE LOOP FROM 0 TO maximum found above
      For ccex = 0 To maxExp
         zidx = 0
         Set lrw = tex.ListRows.Add
         For c = 1 To clmns
            With lrw.Range.Cells(, c)
               'IF THE COLUMN HAVE TO SPLIT
               If Mid$(strFlag, c, 1) <> " " Then
                  tmpUb = UBound(clarr(zidx))
                  'IF THE ARRAY OF SPLITED VALUES EXIST AND INDEX (ccex) <= UPPER BOUND
                  If tmpUb >= 0 And ccex <= tmpUb Then
                     'COPY THE VALUE FROM ARRAY (splitted data)
                     .Value2 = clarr(zidx)(ccex)
                  End If
                  'NEXT SPLITING COLUMN
                  zidx = zidx + 1
               Else
                  'COPY THE ORIGINAL VALUE AS IS
                  .Value2 = t.ListRows(r).Range.Cells(, c)
               End If
            End With
         Next
      Next
   Next
   Set expand_table = tex
   Exit Function
Lerr:
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("expand_table>" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number> " & Err.Number)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function


'*****************************************************************************
'* COPY THIS PUBLIC FUNCTION IN A MODULE
'* This function reverse the result of the previus, creates the original
'* table from the expanded one, having the option not to have duplicate values
'* in the columns made by concatenation
'* ----------------PARAMETERS--------------------
'* ListObject> the table object to expand its data
'* topLeftOfNewTable> the cell to fit the top-left corner of the new table
'* separator> separator string to concatenate values at columns we tranform
'* colsToConcat> ParamArray with indexes of columns to be tranformed eg 3,5,6,7
'*****************************************************************************

Public Function shrink_table(ByRef t As ListObject, topLeftOfNewTable As Range, _
                            allowDuplicatesInConcat As Boolean, separator As String, ParamArray colsToConcat() As Variant) As ListObject
   Dim rws As Long, clmns As Long, r As Long, c As Long, tex As ListObject, strFlag As String
   Dim lbWc As Integer, ubWc As Integer, lrw As ListRow, stmp As Variant
   
   lbWc = LBound(colsToConcat)
   ubWc = UBound(colsToConcat)
   If ubWc < 0 Then Exit Function 'nothing todo
   
   On Error GoTo Lerr
   rws = t.DataBodyRange.Rows.CountLarge
   clmns = t.DataBodyRange.Columns.CountLarge
   
   
   'CREATE A STRING WITH AS SPACES AS THE COLUMNS OF TABLE
   'AT POSITIONS OF colsToConcat() SET "*" (FLAG THE POSITION COLUMNS TO CONCAT)
   strFlag = Space$(clmns)
   For c = lbWc To ubWc
      If colsToConcat(c) <= clmns Then
         Mid$(strFlag, colsToConcat(c), 1) = "*"
      Else
         MsgBox ("shrink_table> Column " & colsToConcat(c) & " out of table bounds - max=" & clmns)
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'IF ALREADY EXISTS A TABLE IN THE POSTOTION OF THE NEW, DELETE IT
   If Not topLeftOfNewTable.ListObject Is Nothing Then
      topLeftOfNewTable.ListObject.Delete
   End If
   
   'COPY THE TABLE
   't.Range.Copy topLeftOfNewTable
   Set tex = topLeftOfNewTable.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, topLeftOfNewTable.Resize(1, t.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count), , xlYes)
   'tex.Name = "TABLEA_CONCAT"
   t.HeaderRowRange.Copy topLeftOfNewTable
      
   Set lrw = tex.ListRows.Add
   t.ListRows(1).Range.Copy lrw.Range
   For r = 2 To rws
      'Set lrw = tex.ListRows.Add
      For c = 1 To clmns
         'With lrw.Range.Cells(, c)
         If Mid$(strFlag, c, 1) = " " Then
            If t.ListRows(r).Range.Cells(, c) <> lrw.Range.Cells(, c) Then
               Set lrw = tex.ListRows.Add
               t.ListRows(r).Range.Copy lrw.Range
               GoTo LnextRow
            End If
         End If
         'End With
      Next
      For c = 1 To clmns
         If Mid$(strFlag, c, 1) = " " Then
            'copy value
            lrw.Range.Cells(, c) = t.ListRows(r).Range.Cells(1, c)
         Else
            'add value
            With lrw.Range.Cells(, c)
               stmp = t.ListRows(r).Range.Cells(1, c)
               If stmp <> vbNullString Then
                  If allowDuplicatesInConcat Then
                     .value = .value & separator & stmp
                  Else
                     If InStr(1, separator & .value & separator, separator & stmp & separator) <= 0 Then
                        .value = .value & separator & stmp
                     End If
                  End If
               End If
            End With
         End If
      Next
LnextRow:
   Next
   Set shrink_table = tex
   Exit Function
Lerr:
   If Err.Number > 0 Then
      MsgBox ("shrink_table>" & vbCrLf & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "error number> " & Err.Number)
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

[image]